# Cell Reference based on Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a sheet and I need a way to track cells based on a reference, in the attached sheet, you can see that there is an **Order Number** column which references a Quantity Row (Qty), the second list below references the same order numbers to determine how many were used. I want a way to automate the **Remaining** column with a formula that calculates how many are left based on the reference (ORD), please help!

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Superuser  **1)** When you post a screenshot of a sheet also include the column and row numbers so that someone answering can put the example with the cells you have in your example, **2)** In general you need to show what you have tried already

Comment: On a side note, not sure what your native language is, but the words in the question do not make sense. *"...track cells based on a reference"* what are you "tracking"? You're "calculating". *"...which references a Quantity Row"* nothing is "referenced" there, it's simply a "...which has a Qty for each row/order".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) on the ***Used*** range, and subtract that from the ***Qty***.

In the first ***Remaining*** cell (the one in the ORD1 row) you can enter (and drag the *fill handle* down to all the orders):

```
=C2-SUMIF($A$16:$B$22,A2,$B$16:$B$22)
```

This will *Subtract* from `C2` (that's the ORD1 Qty cell with the value of `1000`) the *Sum* (total) of the *Used* amount from column `B` (which in the example are in the range of `A16:C22`, expand that to the range of your used list) where the *Order Number* (column `A` matches the Order Number of this row where the formula is (`A2` in the example.)

General piece of advice, put the two datasets (the Order list and the Used list) in two separate ranges, either having the Used data on a 2nd sheet, or on a separate range of columns (starting for example in `F2`). This will make easier referencing ranges as you can simply include the whole column (e.g. `=C2-SUMIF($A:$B,A2,$B:$B)`).